# Developing a Bluetooth app on Mac for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

This is a really simple question that involves no coding and for some reason I am having difficulty finding the answer via google.

I want to develop Blue Tooth applications for iOS.  I've currently written some code using Swift 4 and I've been running it against an IPhone 8 emulator.

However, the problem is that the virtual device doesn't have blue tooth built in, so as a result, to properly develop the app, I need two phones at least.

I'm probably going to buy the two phones; although I hate sinking 200+ dollars on something for really something more of a side-project.  However, before I do, I just want to consult the ether whether or not there exists a cheaper option where I can just continue developing on only my laptop.  (For instance, maybe if I can buy 1 phone and somehow run the peripheral or central code on my laptop directly and use the laptop's blue tooth, or a solution in which I can just run it on my laptop entirely and I don't have to buy anything, i.e. have two iOS VM's and somehow have them talk to each other via the laptop's bluetooth).

TLDR: Is there anyway to develop and test bluetooth applications built on iOS without having to buy 2 iphones.

Comment: If you want both sets of code running on iOS then you need two physical devices.  Core Bluetooth is available on macOS and has the same API.  You would need to write specific UI code for macOS, but Core Bluetooth code written in Swift should be portable between an iOS app and a macOS app.

Comment: Nice, so at least I only would need 1 phone. I guess that's the answer then.

Comment: Note that you don't need an iPhone. Buy a used or refurbished iPod touch or iPad that supports the versions of iOS you need. Probably cheaper than an iPhone.